# How to adjust text’s width and put it at center of post (Visual) editor?

Tags: css, visual-editor, post-editor

[Disclaimer: I'm not a developer of any sort, but willing to take the time. (Can do a bit of CSS, though.) Also, new to this forum.]

I’m using Anders Norén’s Hemingway theme.

I haven’t tried creating child themes yet and I’m not sure whether a solution to this requires one.

My goal, in short, is to make the whole “Edit Post” webpage look like an offline word processor:

1. Make the Visual editor occupy the whole screen. (I use the
   classic editor.) (Done: Collapsed the vertical menu on the left
   side, selected 1-column layout, and disabled “full height editor and
   distraction-free functionality.”)
2. Set a width for the text (because currently text is almost from
   edge to edge of screen)
3. Put text at the center (but “aligned left,” not “justified”).
   This is for the "left and right margins," within the post editor.

It now looks like this.

[image]

How do I do #2 and #3?

Thank you.

Edit: Just to clarify: I'm looking to change how the Visual editor looks--only the Visual editor, not any output the live website would show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option: switch to the Block Editor instead of the Classic Editor. The Block Editor comes with any version of WordPress 5.0 or higher, so update your install, and then if you have the Classic Editor plugin enabled, disable it.

If you have more than one post type, you may want to look into the Gutenberg Ramp plugin, which allows you to choose which post types to use the Block Editor on. You might try just one post type to see how well it works for you.

In any case, the Block Editor has a "Fullscreen Mode" that completely hides the top, left, and right toolbars, and which also has a fixed-width middle column for all of your content. It's very similar to what you're trying to achieve in the Classic Editor.

Comment: Thank you. I have everything updated to their latest version. I'll look into it... I've disabled the Gutenberg editor on the day it was released. I didn't like the "blocks." IIRC Gutenberg broke my draft into one block per paragraph...although I admit I didn't find more time to play with it (maybe because I didn't need it). I'll shift to Gutenberg if I can make it look and feel like the classic editor. (Is that essentially just one huge block, then?) Classic's simplicity is what makes it great, IMO.

Comment: That's correct, each paragraph becomes a separate block, though that happens automatically (you don't have to manually add each block, you just type) and it's easy to go back and forth between them (keyboard arrows will get you there). It takes a little getting used to, but all the other aspects are the clean writing experience you're looking for, and Classic Editor will eventually go away. Might be worth experimenting with on just one post type to ease into it.

Comment: My OP was motivated by my need to use WP's post editor as my main editing and formatting tool. I've been using a word processor in which heavy editing and almost all formatting are done. It's making sense: the Gutenberg devs must have thought exactly what I'm looking for. Users just have to get used to it. Probably also the reason why I don't see "real/popular" solutions to the Classic issue. Will be trying out Gutenberg with a couple of posts. Thank you.

Comment: For what it's worth, the Block Editor also accepts formatted text pasted from tools like Google Docs and Word much better than the Classic Editor.

Comment: I've been a forever user of MS Word until a month ago. Now I also use LibreOffice Writer. LO Writer's what actually pushed me to this; it uses, like, 3x more html than MS Word. Which made me realize I've been using WP's editors quite wrong all in all. Now I paste my ugly first drafts on the Text editor first--giving me zero html tags, which feels really clean--and _then_ I shift to the Visual editor for all editing and formatting.

Comment: Just wanted to say I just discovered the Classic editor part of Gutenberg, the Code Editor. It indeed turns everything into one huge block. The only thing I have to get used to is the editor's line-height that I can't easily modify. Not bad, though. Thank you so much everyone. This is working for me and it outweighs the need to modify functions.php or other complicated things like that (to me).

Answer (score 0):

WordPress uses the JavaScript library of TinyMCE (https://www.tiny.cloud/) with some modifications. In order to do what you're trying to do you will have to modify the way the JavaScript renders the editor.

The WordPress codex shows that there is a hook for applying custom style sheets to the editor.

> The mce_css filter provides a method to add custom stylesheets to the
>   TinyMCE editor window

You can find that [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/mce_css)

I've never tried it before so you'll have to play around with it.  You could also look into the [TinyMCE Advanced Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tinymce-advanced/) it's open source and could be modified.

Now to the big question.  Do you feel comfortable enough learning some JavaScript and PHP in order to do the modifications.  If not you may want to look at something like [UpWork](https://www.upwork.com) to find some help.

Comment: That's indeed the big question. Thanks, John. It's weird because I was excepting that a couple of lines of Additional CSS code would do: I play with my browser's Inspector and I achieve all my goals in real time, but after I save the Additional CSS, everything reverts.

Comment: Sounds lie a plan.  Let me know if you need any help.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm looking to change how the Visual editor looks

I think you should be able to change the Visual editor looks just by adding some [custom editor styles](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editor_Style) with [`add_editor_style()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_editor_style/) function.

Here's a basic example copied from the WP code reference examples.

> Add the following to the functions.php file of your ([*child*](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/)) theme.

```
/**
 * Registers an editor stylesheet for the theme.
 */
function wpdocs_theme_add_editor_styles() {
    add_editor_style( 'custom-editor-style.css' );
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'wpdocs_theme_add_editor_styles' );
```

> Next, create a file named custom-editor-style.css in your (*child*) themes root
>   directory. Any CSS rules added to that file will be reflected within
>   the TinyMCE visual editor. The contents of the file might look like
>   this:

```
body#tinymce.wp-editor { 
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    margin: 10px; 
}

body#tinymce.wp-editor a {
    color: #4CA6CF;
}
```

> How do I do #2 and #3?

I didn't check the css selector, but I think by adding some margin/padding to `body#tinymce.wp-editor` you should get the left and right white-spaces you're looking for.